# what is the difference between state and proof key in oauth 2.0?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

All they do is generate a random value to prevent the code. In proof key, I need send the code challenge and the transfer method. And in the second request to sent the code verifier to check it. If I use state, I just need to use state to check it. Both of them can protect my code. So what is difference in these two ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is used to correlate an authorization redirect to an authorization response (1 client side http event)

PKCE is used to ensure that the authorization redirect and authorization code grant messages are from the same party (2 client side http events)

My write-up may help you visualize this - see steps 6 and 8:
https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/